# Data retrieval parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview

I am developing an android app. for that I have created table product
with columns title, Image1,Image2 , etc
I want to display it in a recycler view or card view. including images. how can i do that...?

```
public class Productfragment extends Fragment {
    private static BUser user = (BUser) ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    private enter code here

 static BStore store = user.getCurrentStore();
    List<BProduct> pets = new ArrayList<BProduct>();
    public String [] ii;
    public Productfragment(){
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
          R.layout.recycler_view, container, false);
        ContentAdapter adapter = new ContentAdapter(recyclerView.getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        return recyclerView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
        //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public SimpleDraweeView picture;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView description;
        public ViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.productfragment, parent, false));
            picture = (SimpleDraweeView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_image);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_title);



            // Adding Snackbar to Action Button inside card
            Button button = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Snackbar.make(v, "Action is pressed",
                      Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            ImageButton favoriteImageButton =
              (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.favorite_button);
            favoriteImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Snackbar.make(v, "Added to Favorite",
                      Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            ImageButton shareImageButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.share_button);
            shareImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Snackbar.make(v, "Share article",
                      Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adapter to display recycler view.
     */
    public class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
        // Set numbers of Card in RecyclerView.
        private static final int LENGTH = 4;


        String [] mylist ;
        public ContentAdapter(Context context) {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Product");
           // query.whereEqualTo("storeI", store.getObjectId());
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

              //  ArrayList<ParseFile>myImage = new ArrayList<ParseFile>();
                public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        for (int i=0; i<scoreList.size(); ++i) {
                             mylist[i] = scoreList.get(i).getString("description");

                           // mylist.add(name);
                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

            });

        }


        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            //holder.picture.setImageURI(mPlacePictures[position % mPlacePictures.length]);
            holder.name.setText(mylist[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return LENGTH;
        }
    }
}
```